# How to conditional format a range based on the values of 3 columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops, conditional-formatting

First of all, I'm sorry for my lack of terms and poor knowledge on the subject. I tried to gather code fragments but no luck. The problem is as follows and I'd very much appreciate it if you could give me some pointers.

I have 3 columns (A B and C) with some values. Then, i have 2 columns D and E which i need to conditional format based on A B and C values. 
The conditions are the following:

D-> If D1 is between A1+B1 and A1+C1 Then D1 stays in black color
    Else D1 appears in red color

E-> If E1 is between B1 and C1 then E1 stays in black color
    Else E1 appears in red color

The process then repeats for D2, D3, etc. Same goes for E.

There will be different sheets with the same code and i probably will be adding several rows to some of them, which might tamper with the definition of the range in A B and C. Also, for each day, I'll be adding two sets of columns (ex: first day I'll add D and E, then F and G, etc). Can i double loop the code on D column for odd numbers? and for even numbers regarding E column?

These are my main questions.

Answer (score 1):

- Select column D (entire column)
- Add a new conditional formatting rule with the formula below and format it red

  ```
  =NOT(AND($D1>$A1,$D1<$B1,$D1<$C1))
  ```
- Select column E (entire column)
- Add a new conditional formatting rule with the formula below and format it red

  ```
  =NOT(AND($E1>$B1,$E1<$C1))
  ```

Note that "between" means the borders (in column A, B, C) are excluded if you want to include them you need to chang `>` to `>=` and `<` to `<=`.

[image]

You can also add a conditional formatting with VBA:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("D").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=NOT(AND($D1>$A1,$D1<$B1,$D1<$C1))")
    .Font.Color = -16776961
    .Font.TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

*But note that the formula in `Formula1` must be localized. That means if you plan to run this on a non-english Excel then this formula must be converted to this localized non-english formula.*

Comment: Thank you for your input! I'll try this asap. Also, will i be able to click and drag? There will be hundreds of values and series of 2 columns sets to add. I was thinking of using vba to shorten the proccess instead of creating rules as i go..

Comment: Please try and test on your own before asking further hypotetical questions. If you drag/drop a value in column D/E then you will mess up your existing conditional formatting, and you will need to delete it and set the condition again. Instead of drag/drop you should cut and past values only (without formatting) to keep the conditional formatting in place. • Drag/Drop of cells will always move the cell value **including** all formattings.